# Pandoc - how to list available styles / themes / templates?

Tags: pandoc

I wonder how to check available styles / themes / templates in Pandoc? And yeah, I really don't know how it is actually called in Pandoc - I mean a style applied to the output document (what font will be used, how the pics / tables will be signed etc).

Also - how do I know which style is used by default?